# Google Slides viewer finish event

Tags: google-docs

i'm using google slide in a embedded iframe, I've published it and I'm able to autostart but i can only autoloop or stop it once finished.I'd like, for example, to change iframe content once finished, there's a way or an api for google viewer to send an event once my presentation is finished.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a short/simple chrome extension that will do that.
Or use this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-reload/ofojbjgaaddibdfpmmjeonahgbacejid